skip_on_failure Flag with Pydantic V2?
The root_validator that was available with Pydantic V1 allowed a flag called skip_on_failure, which allowed other validators to be run even if prior ones failed (when set to True).
Is there a way to achieve using the model_validator offered by V2? I cannot figure it out from the docs.
